# Regular Expression to validate Solo debit card

Tags: regex

I would like a regular expression that would enable me to validate a Solo debit card.

The card number has IIN ranges of 6334 and 6767 and a length of 16, 18 , 19. Though this is not in use currently, I would like to learn how I could write a regex for it.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: what is a solo debit card, and what are the rules that make it valid or not?

Comment: I have just edited my post to add more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw in a comment you wanted dashes.  You should update your question to reflect this.
The following will match with dashes.  It matches the start of string, the first possible sequence of numbers, then a sequence of a dash then four numbers three times, then either end of string, or 2 to 3 digits and end of string.

```
^(6767|6334)(-\d{4}){3}($|\d{2,3}$)
```

Here are some results

```
6334-1231-1231-1231 // works
6767-1312-1231-1231123 // works
6334-1231-1231-1231 // works
6767-1312-1231-12312 // fails last sequence is 5 digits
6868-1232-1233-1231 // fails start is not valid
6767-1231-1232-2312-1 // fails additional dash
```

I saw another answer checked for digits 5-9 after 6334.  If that is required, the new regex is

```
^(6334-[5-9]|6767-\d)\d{3}(-\d{4}){2}($|\d{2,3}$)
```

You can test with this [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/)

Comment: This worked so well! I added a couple of other conditions to the expression and it worked too. Thanks much again!

Comment: I simplified the original answer and provided and alternative.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
(^(6334)[5-9](\d{11}$|\d{13,14}$)) |(^(6767)(\d{12}$|\d{14,15}$))
```

Comment: This expression is good but it validates numbers in the format [4444]. What do I include in the expression so it can validate formats like [4 4 4 4] or [4-4-4-4]. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Regex for Solo debit card:

```
(^(5[0678])\d{11,18}$)(^(6[^05])\d{11,18}$)(^(601)[^1]\d{9,16}$)(^(6011)\d{9,11}$)(^(6011)\d{13,16}$)(^(65)\d{11,13}$)(^(65)\d{15,18}$)(^(49030)[2-9](\d{10}$\d{12,13}$))(^(49033)[5-9](\d{10}$\d{12,13}$))(^(49110)[1-2](\d{10}$\d{12,13}$))(^(49117)[4-9](\d{10}$\d{12,13}$))(^(49118)[0-2](\d{10}$\d{12,13}$))(^(4936)(\d{12}$\d{14,15}$))
```

[Here](http://php3ch0.blogspot.com/2008/05/regex-for-uk-cardit-debit-cards.html) you will find details along with others!